# How to get eclipse Helios to recognise HTML5 elements

Tags: eclipse, html

Hi all I have spent some time googling this but to no avail. If anyone could point me in the right direction of some resources on getting my eclipse bundle recognising the new HTML5 tags that would be greatly appreciated. I am getting annoyed with all these little warning signs. I am using

Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Release

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Looks like Helios SR1 (3.6.1) includes 3.2.2 of the web tools, which has some HTML5 support. See http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-dev/msg07795.html and http://kellicker.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/jsdt-html5-support-in-helios-sr1/

Answer (score 1):

The way i solve this is adding this tag line in the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
**<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />**
<title>Canvas tutorial</title>
......
...
.
```

And now the canvas tag gets recognize

Comment: in HTML5 , it should be written as `<meta charset="utf-8" />`